# How to refresh a simple Datatables table when adding new rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I thought this one would be simple, but I can't find a reference that is not about ajax loaded data or data supplied in an array. I am using DataTables on an existing HTML table with this basic code:

```
  $('table.wizard').dataTable({
        lengthChange: false,
        iDisplayLength: 100,
        order: [[9, 'desc']]
    });
```

I am adding rows to a table, dynamically, as data records are found like this:

```
var $body = $('table.wizard tbody');
$tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($body).attr({ 'id': 'sku' + item.MerchantSKU, 'data-sku': item.MerchantSKU });
// then append the individual tds
[snip]
// Now how to tell the datatables it has changed?
```

How do I inform DataTables about the new rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a few experiments, as the documentation and examples are not very clear for DOM tables, it turns out you can use the same `row.add()` method for adding HTML `TR`s as you would for objects and arrays. You then call the [`draw()` method](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) to make the changes visible:

e.g.

```
dt.row.add($tr);
dt.draw();
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/HEDvf/2205/

Unfortunately it does allow you to refresh additions made with jQuery (which is ideally what I really wanted to allow for transparent use of DataTables) :(

**Final solution (for now):**

I added a custom `appendRow()` jQuery extension, that checks if the table is a DataTable and redirects the append via the DataTables api if needed:

```
// Assume we only append to one table at a time (otherwise rows need to be cloned)
$.fn.appendRow = function ($rows) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("dataTables_wrapper")) {
        var dt = $(this).dataTable().api();
        $rows.each(function () {
            dt.row.add(this);
        });
        dt.draw();
    } else {
        $(this).append($rows);
    }
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/HEDvf/2212/

Comment: one liner: dt.row.add($tr).draw();

Comment: @Daniel: I am looking for a way that allows jQuery additions to be made independent of DataTables, to allow for same table to be usable with DataTables on or off. If yours had worked that would have been closer

Comment: Then you should write a function that checks if your table is wrapped by an element with `dataTables_wrapper` style class, and if so call the datatables refresh code, otherwise call the plain table refresh code (if you got some)

Comment: @Daniel: Good idea. At least then it will only have one code path. I will probably wrap it as a `$(element).appendRow()` jQuery extension and post it here.

Comment: The `dataTables_wrapper` class is being added by the datatables api... you just need to check for its presence...

Comment: Its there, see: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/2210/ , this could be your check for its presence `$('#example').closest('.dataTables_wrapper').length === 1` , sure you can use some other indicator of datatables usage...

Comment: @Daniel: `.parent().hasClass()` will avoid problems with nested tables. Have added extension code and example.

Comment: How would you add only unique rows or replace data if one of the columns contains the same data?

Comment: @DanielHarris: I would put a unique id in the row to find and target replacements. Nowadays you might use another product (knockout, angular, React etc) to modify row data efficiently.