# Datatable Methods not working after adding Row with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Ive got a problem to solve. With .append() I do add new rows which have input fields. But the problem is, that after appending new rows no methods work on them. No methods like search, responsive button etc.

I tried a lot but I couldnt figure it out...After clicking on a button a new Row gets added to the #table.

```
var poAddRowTable = $('#table').DataTable();
$('button').on('click', function () {
    addRowFunc(true)
});

addRowFunc = function () {
    var previousRow = $('#table tr:last');
    var newRow = $(previousRow).clone(true, true);

    $('#table tbody').append(newRow);
    $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
}
```

Comment: from your problem it looks like you are binding the event listener to elements generated dynamically therefore it is not working. if you can please share the html structure I might be able to help

Comment: You should use `poAddRowTable.row.add(newRow).draw()`

Comment: @davidkonrad you sir are da best ;-) awesome thanks it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to use DataTable.row.add() for adding a new row to the data table.
Your addRowFunc should be updated like this

```
addRowFunc = function () {

    // Clone data from last row
    var lastRow = $('#table tr:last');
    var newRowdata = [];
    $('#table tr:last').find('td').each(function() {
        newRowdata.push($(this).text());
    }); 

    // Add new row to table
    poAddRowTable.row.add(newRowdata).draw();

    $("html, body").scrollTop($(document).height());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to refresh your table after appending, the following link can help :

[How to refresh a simple Datatables table when adding new rows with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511128/how-to-refresh-a-simple-datatables-table-when-adding-new-rows-with-jquery)